# Sort a List(Of Tuple)

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, list, tuples

I have a list like this:

```
Dim Results_List As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String, Long))
```

With those contents:

```
(B, a, 5000)
(G, a, 1000)
(B, b, 8000)
(G, b, 2000)
```

Can I use LINQ (or whateverelse but not using a slow FOR) to sort the items by the Long numbers in ascending mode as this?:

```
(G, a, 1000)
(G, b, 2000)
(B, a, 5000)
(B, b, 8000)
```

Comment: In what way is that *descending*? Looks like ascending to me...

Comment: Note, your result shows ascending order, not descending.

Comment: Thanks for the acclaration guys, I edited that in my question. (PS: I don't think that is a reason for a -1)

Comment: Why do you think a For loop would be slow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var sortedItems = list.OrderBy(t => t.Item3);
```

Comment: The translation to VB.NET: Results_List = Results_List.OrderBy(Function(X) X.Item3).ToList

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even by using the internal `Sort` of `List`:

```
Results_List.Sort(Function(p As Tuple(Of String, String, Long), q As Tuple(Of String, String, Long)) p.Item3.CompareTo(q.Item3))
```

Note that this will sort the `Results_List` directly, while the `OrderBy` will returned a new, sorted, enumerable.